# How to remove data from API with HTTP Request [React TS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so I've been working on an admin control panel for a page that displays a list of cards that once clicked, redirect the user to either a video ora text-based link. I must also add a CRUD feature that allows me to edit / remove posts from the API provided.

The API is locally hosted, so requesting "localhost:3000/videos/{Id}" will load up the object with the following fields: "id", "url", "title" and "thumbnail"

I have a class that is used for making the card, called HelpCard.tsx The code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import "../help/HelpList";
import spinner from "../help/spinner.gif";
import { string, number } from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface State {
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  id: string;
  imageLoading?: boolean;
  tooManyRequests?: boolean;
}

export default class HelpCard extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    id: "",
    title: "",
    imageLoading: true,
    tooManyRequests: false,
    thumbnail: "",
    deleteProduct: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url, title, thumbnail } = this.props;
    const id = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];

    this.setState({
      id,
      title,
      thumbnail,
      imageLoading: true,
      tooManyRequests: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isThumbnail = this.state.thumbnail;
    const adminhelpcard = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {isThumbnail ? (
          <div className="horizontalCard">
            <div className="innerCard">
              <div className="leftImage">
                <img
                  className="Sprite"
                  onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                  onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                  src={this.state.thumbnail}
                  style={
                    this.state.tooManyRequests
                      ? { display: "none" }
                      : this.state.imageLoading
                      ? { display: "null" }
                      : { display: "null" }
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="rightText">
                <div className="card-body">
                  {this.state.title}
                  <div className="cardButtons">
                    <button className="btn btn-update btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => adminhelpcard.deleteProduct(this.state.id)}
                      className="btn btn-outline-primary">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And then I have the HelpList.tsx module that is responsible for displaying the cards in the form of a list. and the code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpCard from "./HelpCard";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";
import { Button } from "components/ui";

interface State {
  url: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
}

interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface Props {}

export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
  };

  loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ adminhelpcard: res.data });
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            adminhelpcard: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${this.state.id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.adminhelpcard);
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.adminhelpcard ? (
            <div className="row">
              <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadAdminHelpCard}
                hasMore={this.state.url ? true : false}
                threshold={0}
                loader={
                  <div className="loader" key={0}>
                    Loading ...
                  </div>
                }>
                {this.state.adminhelpcard.map((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard, i) => (
                  <HelpCard
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                  />
                ))}
              </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading Cards</h1>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

from the "deleteProduct" function in the line of code:

```
onClick={() => adminhelpcard.deleteProduct(this.state.id)}
```

When I try to click the delete button on the helpCards, it says that the no function called "deleteProduct" is recognized. How do I go about fixing this?

--------------------------EDIT----------------------------

Error given for adding deleteProduct to HelpCard component.

"No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): HelpCard', gave the following error.
    Type '{ key: string; title: string; url: string; thumbnail: string; deleteProduct: (id: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'deleteProduct' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to pass the `deleteProduct` function as a `prop` to the `HelpCard` component.

So in your `HelpList.tsx`, add another prop to the `<HelpCard/>` element as follows.

```
<HelpCard
    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
    title={adminhelpcard.title}
    url={adminhelpcard.url}
    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
/>
```

Then you need to use it from the `onClick` handler within the `HelpCard` component.

```
<button
    onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.state.id)}
    className="btn btn-outline-primary">
        Delete
</button>
```

Probably you may need to change the `Props` interface in your `HelpCard` to cater to this new prop as well.

```
interface Props {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  deleteProduct: (id: any) => void;
}
```

Comment: Where / how would I put the top chunk of code in the HelpCard.tsx? or how would I pass the deleteproduct

Comment: It goes in your `HelpList.tsx`

Comment: Updated my answer. In your `HelpList.tsx`'s render method you already have a `HelpCard` element. Just add another prop to it as shown.

Comment: Adding "deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct} to <HelpCard/> gives the error that was added to my original question.

Comment: You may need to modify your `Props` interface as well. Updated my answer with that.

Comment: The error remains even after updating the props with what you've shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200160/discussion-between-zadders-and-udith-gunaratna).